# Android color not working

Tags: android, themes

My android project

`AndoidManifest.xml` has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
         <meta-data 
             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
             android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" /> 
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

I have customised theme under `res\values\themes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
      <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
      <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"  
          parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item> 
       </style>      <!-- ActionBar styles -->

       <style name="MyActionBar"            
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
       <item name="android:background">#ffccff</item>
       </style>  
</resources>
```

But the color doesn't seem to be reflecting in the android application. Still shows everything in black.

Comment: Did you check whether "MyActionBar" is set to be transparent, and the parent object is black? Also please provide more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: #FFFFCCFF does this works

Comment: it does work @hitech , can you post that as an answer,I'll accept the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because seems like you are missing the alpha part of the color, in stead of setting the color as

```
<item name="android:background">#ffccff</item>
```

You should actually add the Alpha to Full by adding it as shown below:

```
<item name="android:background">#ffffccff</item>
```

Notice that FF has been added before the RGB Hex number.

Hope this helps.

Regards